# How can i make this grid group-up when i filter the elements?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set up a flutter application to view the list of names of people in an event. I have also setup a filter so i can see different guest statuses. However, ever since i switched to a grid view. This filter hasnt been working, when i filter elements, they are not grouped up (Picture) the white space are elements who are supposedly have other statuses than confirmed

[image: Screenshot]

Code for grid view

```dart
SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: myStream,
      builder:
          (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshots) {
        if (snapshots.connectionState ==
            ConnectionState.active) {
          return AlignedGridView.custom(
            gridDelegate:
                SliverSimpleGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
            mainAxisSpacing: 4,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshots.data?.docs.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

filter

```dart
const SizedBox(
  width: 20,
),
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  dropdownColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 122, 135, 193),
  icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list, color: Colors.black),
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: <String>[
          'All',
          'confirmed',
          'rejected',
          'Not yet',
          'failed'
        ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(
              value,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
),
```

The list of people who are supposed to be coming should be next to each other grid style. However, right now they are spaced out (maybe due to the hidden elemenets of people coming? But it was working when it was ListView.

Comment: Can you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

since you are using thrid party package, documentation is your friend.

I see you are using `AlignedGridView.custom` , and based on example in the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#quilted) , pleaseadd the pattern.

for example:

```
GridView.custom(
  gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4,
    repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
    pattern: [
      QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
    ],
  ),
```

you may need different pattern. change it based on your needs